# What is the sum of this series $\sum_n{n\cdot(2/3)^{n-1}}$?

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

What is the sum of this series $$\sum_n{n\cdot(2/3)^{n-1}}$$ What criteria can i use? And how should I use it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hint: Note that
$$nx^{n-1}=(x^n)', \quad n\geq 1.$$
Consequently, formally
$$\left(\sum_{n\geq 0} x^n \right)'=\sum_{n\geq 1} n x^{n-1},$$
now recognize the left as the usual geometric series... conclude.

Answer (score 0):

$${\frac {1}{1-x}}=\sum _{n=0}^{\infty }x^{n}\quad {\text{ for }}|x|<1\!$$
differentiate it 
$${\frac {1}{(1-x)^{2}}}=\sum _{n=1}^{\infty }nx^{n-1}$$
then plug $x=\frac{2}{3}$